# ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis in LSTM Python

Tags: python, lstm, forecasting

I am using LSTM to predict the Water Consumption based on other features in the dataset. The code is perfectly generating the predictions for the test set but giving `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 1` when I tried to forecast the values for future. Can anyone please help me! Any guidance will be helpful in this matter.

Data:

```
Year    Population  Water_Consumption   Temp_Change Groundwater_Availability
0   2003    590288  287.23  28.5    721.750
1   2004    621880  312.77  28.4    721.156
2   2005    655069  344.76  28.4    718.000
3   2006    696183  363.51  28.5    712.200
4   2007    744867  377.48  28.6    706.400
5   2008    797031  409.29  28.1    700.600
6   2009    852689  458.69  28.5    694.800
7   2010    912318  471.40  29.2    689.000
8   2011    964168  452.84  28.8    683.200
9   2012    1019041 506.61  28.9    677.400
10  2013    1076874 522.34  28.2    671.600
11  2014    1138076 536.03  28.3    665.800
12  2015    1202756 536.59  29.3    660.000
13  2016    1271112 523.18  28.7    654.200
14  2017    1343353 523.77  29.3    648.400
15  2018    1419699 512.81  29.3    642.600
16  2019    1452057 505.39  29.1    636.700
17  2020    1482816 507.55  29.0    631.000
18  2021    1511768 510.33  29.5    625.200
19  2022    1539830 512.56  29.3    619.400
20  2023    1566999 517.92  30.1    613.600
```

This part is working fine:

```
# Extracting relevant columns for LSTM
data = df[['Water_Consumption', 'Population', 'Temp_Change', 'Groundwater_Availability']]

# Normalize the data using Min-Max scaling
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

# Define the look-back period (number of time steps to consider)
look_back = 3

# Create a function to prepare the data for LSTM
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])  # Target variable is in the first column
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

# Prepare the data
X, y = create_dataset(scaled_data, look_back)

# Train-test split (90-10 ratio)
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.9)
trainX, testX = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
trainY, testY = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]

# Reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, trainX.shape[2]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], look_back, testX.shape[2]))

# Build the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1000, input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# Make predictions on the test set
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# Invert predictions to original scale
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(np.concatenate((testPredict, testX[:, -1, 1:]), axis=1))[:, 0]
testY = scaler.inverse_transform(np.concatenate((testY.reshape(-1, 1), testX[:, -1, 1:]), axis=1))[:, 0]

# Print the predicted values for the test set
print("Actual vs Predicted Values for the Test Set:")
for i in range(len(testY)):
    print(f"Actual: {testY[i]:.2f} | Predicted: {testPredict[i]:.2f}")
```

But getting error here:

```
# Reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], look_back, X.shape[2]))

# Build the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1000, input_shape=(look_back, X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# Make predictions for future years (2024 to 2040)
future_years = 20
future_predictions = []

# Use the last 'look_back' years from the original data to start predicting
current_sequence = scaled_data[-look_back:, :]

for _ in range(future_years):
    # Reshape and predict for the next year
    current_sequence_reshaped = np.reshape(current_sequence, (1, look_back, current_sequence.shape[1]))
    next_prediction_scaled = model.predict(current_sequence_reshaped)
    
    # Append the predicted value to the sequence
    current_sequence = np.append(current_sequence[1:, :], next_prediction_scaled, axis=0)
    
    # Invert the prediction to the original scale
    next_prediction_original_scale = scaler.inverse_transform(np.concatenate((next_prediction_scaled, current_sequence[-1, 1:]), axis=1))[:, 0]
    
    # Append the prediction to the list
    future_predictions.append(next_prediction_original_scale)

# Print the forecasted values
print("\nForecasted Values for the Future (2024 to 2040):")
for i, prediction in enumerate(future_predictions):
    year = 2024 + i
    print(f"Year {year}: {prediction:.2f}")
```